# MAP when the prior of the parameter is defined piecewise

Tags: map-estimation

As defined on Wikipedia, $$\hat{\theta}_{MAP} = \underset{\theta}{\mathrm{argmax}} f(x | \theta) g(\theta)$$

Then, to actually obtain theta-hat-MAP, we could set the derivative of the above (or their log) to zero and solve for $\hat{\theta}_{MAP}$ then check the second derivative to ensure maximum.

However, what happens if $g(\theta)$ is defined piecewise? For example, $g(\theta)$ is different for $\theta \leq 0$ and $\theta \geq 0$. How should we take the derivative of $g(\theta)$? Do we sum up the derivatives of the different definitions of $g(\theta)$?

Comment: No, you do not "sum up the derivatives of the different definitions of $g(θ)$".  You could check for zeros in the first derivative in each of the pieces, and then find which of those roots *or the locations of the ends of the pieces* give the highest posterior density in $g(\theta)$.

Comment: The derivative will be piecewise and you have to check whether it exists at the boundaries

Comment: got it, thank you!